# How do I evaluate $\lim_{h \to \infty} e^{h(1-s)}$?

Tags: integration, limits, laplace-transform

I'm messing around with Laplace, and was trying to find the transform of $e^{t}$ and I have to evaluate $$\lim_{h \to \infty} e^{h(1-s)}$$  I figure if $s=1$, the limit is $1$.  If $0≤s<1$, the limit is $\infty$. If $s>1$, the limit is $0$.

WolframAlpha tells me the answer is complex infinity.  I don't know what that is.

When I ask WolframAlpha for the transform of $e^t$, it says $\frac{1}{s-1}$, which would assume that s>1, though it doesn't mention this.  **What if $s$ isn't greater than 1?**

Comment: When you compute Laplace transforms, you should assume that `s` is real and sufficiently large, or is complex and has real part sufficiently large. Try to compute the Laplace transform of 1, for example: you need to know that `s` is positive.

Comment: Where does this assumption that s is large come from?

Comment: The integral won't converge if $s$ is too small: the factor $e^{-st}$ in the integrand, as $t$ goes from 0 to $\infty$, can be problematic if $s<0$.

Comment: I understand that if $s$ is negative, then it won't converge.  But if $s$ is tiny, it still converges, just much slower.  Obviously I'd like to use the one that converges the fastest, so I suppose that's why s should be large.  Thanks, I think I get it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple approaches to computing the Laplace transform of $e^t$ but the "slickest" way is just to use the derivative rule:
$$\mathcal{L}_t[f'(t)](s) = s\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](s) - f(0).$$
Then you can notice that the derivative of $e^t$ is just $e^t$, so you can solve for $\mathcal{L}_t[e^t]$ in the above equation. This gives $\mathcal{L}_t[e^t] = \frac{1}{s-1}$.

The derivative rule is just computed with integration by parts, which you could use for $e^t$ directly. See [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html).

---

If you look at the page I linked, it sates:

> The Laplace transform existence theorem states that, if $f(t)$ is
>   piecewise continuous on every finite interval in $[0,\infty)$
>   satisfying $$f(t) \leq Me^{at}$$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$, then
>   $\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](s)$ exists for all $s > a$.

So basically, given $a$ you need to find an $M$ such that $\log M \geq (1-a)t$ for every $t\in[0,\infty)$. You can obviously do this when $a \geq 1$ because the RHS is always negative or $0$ in that case. If $a < 1$ you can't, because the RHS is unbounded. So $a = 1$ is the best choice here and $\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](s)$ exists for $s > 1$.

---

Comment: Thanks, but my question was really about the way the limit changes if different assumptions are made about $s$.

Comment: Edited to add the explanation from the page I linked.